# What procedure do steel plants use to recycle water vapor?

Tags: process-engineering, recycling

As you may know Steel plants and Tile Factories use a lot of water. I want to know how do these factories recycle water vapor which is mixed with flue gases to reuse it?
Do they take advantage of Heat Exchangers or other type of condensers?
If they do what kind of them?

Comment: Flue gasses are acidic and "dirty".  Pulling water out that is clean enough for industrial use is likely expensive.  Cooling it to liquid is expensive.  Dirty can mean a few salts, or some other innocuous seeming but industrially problematic in production.

Comment: Yes, but how do these industries are reusing their consumed water? BTW they may take advantage of alkaline for the produced acidic liquid.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a company that recycles their flue gas water in the manner you describe? I have never heard of such a practice outside of residential and commercial high-efficiency central, forced-air heaters.

Comment: It just occurred to me: do you mean recycling the water used for air pollution scrubbing in, say, a [wet scrubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_scrubber)?